# Loading Spalsh Screen before application launching

Tags: java, screen, loading, splash-screen

How can I do to create a loading jframe without title bar like Eclipse in the image...
[image]

I used setUndecorate() to remove the title bar and a thread to wait 3 seconds then open the main window but it wouldn't work ...
I'm not thinking to use a progressbar...

How can I do??

Thanks in advance.

Best rgards,

Ali

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way could be what you already thought of: display an undecorated JFrame when the application starts, then instead of just waiting for a few seconds (you could do that as well, if you want users to read some info) just keep initializing the application. When initialization is finished, close the "splash screen" (undecorated JFrame) and open the actual application JFrame.

This would enable you to display dynamic information (like a progress bar if you later want to, some text etc.). If all you need is a static splash screen, go for Andrew's advice and use the built in splash screen functionality.

Comment: an *undecorated JFrame* practically means the entire slow disk part of loading the VM and JRE has completed + at least the 1st jar in the classpath to initialize. The splash screen idea is to be light and fast to load.

Comment: As I said, if a static splash screen is sufficient, he should go for the build in functionality. Using SplashScreen class for dynamic splash screens would require the JVM to start first, too, wouldn't it?

Comment: "..dynamic splash screens would require the JVM to start first, too, wouldn't it?"  True, but it comes down to which **parts** of the JRE need to load before being able to display a splash and (in this case) alter it.  And that reminds me that pre 1.6 & ex JWS, the way to do what you suggest was using a (java.awt.)Window, rather than a Frame or JFrame.  Loading a Swing class triggers many other classes to be loaded.

Comment: the splash is handled separately by native code, modifying the splash screen requires indeed to have the JVM started but running Swing on top of AWT requires extra time as well (JFream proposal), on 64bit -server hotspot it's actually noticeable even on not-so-shabby hardware, the compilation of the classes takes some time. On a side note; AWT does expend best effort to avoid touching swing (even though there are some minor dependencies) by  using a few tricks.

Answer (score 2):

See the [`SplashScreen`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/SplashScreen.html) class.

It includes the [`createGraphics()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/SplashScreen.html#createGraphics--) method that returns a [`Graphics2D`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html) object that can be written to.  You would need to draw the progress bar to the graphics object.

---

[Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) also offers splash screen functionality, configured in the launch file.  But the graphics object of the JWS splash screen are not available to the app. (so no 'progress bar').

Comment: if the WS starts the java console, the splash screen is wasted, the slowest part of the WS is usually the validation of the signatures in the jars.

Comment: What is 'the WS'?  Is that referring to Java Web Start?

Comment: @bestsss Good point.  OTOH note that: 1) The JWS splash is not in any Jar.  2) The 'validate Jar files' is unnecessary for any JWS app. that is sand-boxed (though I cannot guarantee the JWS client skips validation for signed Jars) 3)  I would need to see a launch of a trusted app. to be **convinced** the splash only appears *after* the code is validated/accepted (though I suspect that is the case).  I have to concede - the SplashScreen for a double-click Jar has more functionality and less pitfalls in this case.

Comment: the verification is not done by the WS but the classloader itself (any URLClassLoader would verify a signed jar regardless). Sandboxed applications are usually small enough not to need the splash, though (reminds me Win7 conservative recommendations on splash screens). My point is that since the java console is a Frame it hides the splash screen.