# Issues with SwingWorker and JProgressBar

Tags: java, swing, progress-bar, swingworker

I need to convert a any image given to a byte array for encryption requirement. I'm using JProgressBar to monitor the conversion progress in case the chosen image is large:

```
File p= new File("C:\");
BufferedImage oImg = ImageIO.read(p);
ByteArrayOutputStream ba = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ImageIO.write(oImg, "jpg", ba);
ba.flush();

ProgressBar pb = new ProgressBar();
Thread thread = new Thread(pb);
thread.join();
pb.fireTask(ba.toByteArray());
```

I defined a `ProgressBar` class that uses `SwingWorker` as follows:

```
public class ProgressBar extends JPanel implements Runnable {

    private JProgressBar progressBar;
    private Task task;
    private byte[] imgByteArray;


    public void run() {
        createGUI();
    }

    // Create the GUI
    private void createGUI() {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Converting...");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JComponent newContentPane = new ProgressBar();
        newContentPane.setOpaque(true); 
        frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        progressBar = new JProgressBar(0, 100);
        progressBar.setBounds(20, 22, 419, 20);
        progressBar.setValue(0);
        progressBar.setStringPainted(true);
        panel.add(progressBar);
        add(panel);
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(20, 20, 20, 20));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }


    /**
     * Firing the Task
     */
    public void fireTask(byte[] imgArray) {
        System.arraycopy(imgArray, 0, imgByteArray, 0, imgByteArray.length);
        setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.WAIT_CURSOR));
        task = new Task();
        task.execute();
    }



    class Task extends SwingWorker<Void, Void> {
        @Override
        public Void doInBackground() {

            for (int i=0; i<=imgByteArray.length; i++){ 

                progressBar.setValue(i); 
                progressBar.repaint(); 
                try{
                    Thread.sleep(50);
                } catch (InterruptedException err){
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

           public void done() {
               Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
               setCursor(null); // turn off the wait cursor
               }
        }
}
```

Sadly, this error occurs!

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ciphers.ProgressBar.fireTask(ProgressBar.java:65)
    at ciphers.Images.imageEncryption(Images.java:310)
    at ciphers.Images.access$1(Images.java:286)
    at ciphers.Images$2.actionPerformed(Images.java:184)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:4
02)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
```

I don't know what is wrong with my code! I read `SwingWorker` and `JProgressBar` before writing this code but I feel I'm missing something! Can I get a hint that helps.

Thank you :)

Comment: You're missing the point of using a SwingWorker and need to go back and re-read the tutorials and examples you have been previously provided. There is no need for a separate thread, as the SwingWorker has its own threading capabilities. For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24815494/using-jprogressbar-while-converting-image-to-byte-array/24815609#24815609)

Comment: The basic idea is, the SwingWorker should be used to convert the image, within its doInBackground method, you can use the SwingWorkers progress property to trigger updates back to the UI so that the UI could update the progress bar.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You seem to not understand what `SwingWorker` does.

`SwingWorker` provides a means by which you can execute long running tasks outside the context of the Event Dispatching Thread.  This means that your program won't appear to have become frozen.  The benefit of using a `SwingWorker` (over using a simple `Thread`) is that it provides a number of easy to use methods to re-sync the updates back to the EDT, which is indented to stop you from breaking the single thread rules of Swing: No UI element should be created or modified on any thread other then the EDT.

Tak a closer look at [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) and [`javax.swing.SwingWorker<T,V>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) and [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details

[image: Convert]

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.imageio.ImageReader;
import javax.imageio.ImageWriter;
import javax.imageio.event.IIOReadProgressListener;
import javax.imageio.event.IIOWriteProgressListener;
import javax.imageio.stream.ImageInputStream;
import javax.imageio.stream.ImageOutputStream;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class ConvertImage {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ConvertImage();
    }

    public ConvertImage() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                TestPane tp = new TestPane();

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(tp);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);

                tp.convert(new File("/your/image/somewhere"));
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel implements ImageConverstionListener {

        private JLabel label = new JLabel("Waiting...");
        private JProgressBar pb = new JProgressBar();

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            add(label, gbc);
            add(pb, gbc);
        }

        public void convert(File file) {
            ConverterWorker worker = new ConverterWorker(file, this);
            worker.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void propertyChange(final PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
                    if ("progress".equalsIgnoreCase(evt.getPropertyName())) {
                        pb.setValue((int) evt.getNewValue());
                    }
                }
            });
            worker.execute();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        public void failedToConvertImage(File source, Throwable cause) {
            cause.printStackTrace();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "<html>Failed to convert " + source + "<br>" + cause.getMessage(), "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }

        @Override
        public void imageConverted(File source, byte[] bytes) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Converted image to " + bytes.length + " bytes", "Converted", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }

        @Override
        public void setMessage(String msg) {
            label.setText(msg);
        }

    }

    public interface ImageConverstionListener {

        public void failedToConvertImage(File source, Throwable cause);

        public void imageConverted(File source, byte[] bytes);

        public void setMessage(String msg);

    }

    public class ConverterWorker extends SwingWorker<ByteArrayOutputStream, String> {

        private File source;
        private ImageConverstionListener listener;

        public ConverterWorker(File source, ImageConverstionListener listener) {
            this.source = source;
            this.listener = listener;
        }

        @Override
        protected void process(List<String> chunks) {
            listener.setMessage(chunks.get(chunks.size() - 1));
        }

        @Override
        protected ByteArrayOutputStream doInBackground() throws Exception {
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            publish("Reading image...");
            try (ImageInputStream iis = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(source)) {
                Iterator<ImageReader> readers = ImageIO.getImageReaders(iis);
                if (readers.hasNext()) {
                    ImageReader reader = readers.next();
                    reader.addIIOReadProgressListener(new IIOReadProgressListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void sequenceStarted(ImageReader source, int minIndex) {
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void sequenceComplete(ImageReader source) {
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void imageStarted(ImageReader source, int imageIndex) {
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void imageProgress(ImageReader source, float percentageDone) {
                            setProgress(Math.round(percentageDone));
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void imageComplete(ImageReader source) {
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void thumbnailStarted(ImageReader source, int imageIndex, int thumbnailIndex) {
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void thumbnailProgress(ImageReader source, float percentageDone) {
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void thumbnailComplete(ImageReader source) {
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void readAborted(ImageReader source) {
                        }
                    });
                    reader.setInput(iis);
                    try {
                        BufferedImage img = reader.read(0);

                        publish("Converting image...");
                        try (ImageOutputStream ios = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(baos)) {
                            Iterator<ImageWriter> writers = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("png");
                            if (writers.hasNext()) {
                                ImageWriter writer = writers.next();
                                writer.addIIOWriteProgressListener(new IIOWriteProgressListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void imageStarted(ImageWriter source, int imageIndex) {
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void imageProgress(ImageWriter source, float percentageDone) {
                                        setProgress(Math.round(percentageDone));
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void imageComplete(ImageWriter source) {
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void thumbnailStarted(ImageWriter source, int imageIndex, int thumbnailIndex) {
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void thumbnailProgress(ImageWriter source, float percentageDone) {
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void thumbnailComplete(ImageWriter source) {
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void writeAborted(ImageWriter source) {
                                    }
                                });

                                writer.setOutput(ios);
                                try {
                                    writer.write(img);
                                } finally {
                                    writer.removeAllIIOWriteProgressListeners();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } finally {
                        reader.removeAllIIOReadProgressListeners();
                    }
                }
            }
            return baos;
        }

        @Override
        protected void done() {
            try {
                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = get();
                listener.imageConverted(source, baos.toByteArray());
            } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException ex) {
                listener.failedToConvertImage(source, ex);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Yes, actually I didn't understand it so I had hard times to figure out how to engaged it in my application. Thanks you so much for your help :)

Comment: Another reference to Java's official "tutorial" on this topic and I'll official lose it.

Comment: @ojonugwaochalifu It’s still the best place to get started, after all, most of us didn’t have SO when we started

Comment: This answer is a work of art, ty vm for posting it.

Comment: However, I must echo the comment by @OjonugwaJudeOchalifu -- the tutorial for ***`JProgressBar` in particular*** was uncharacteristically bad. They started with the complex version (JProgressBar), then 2/3 of the way through, they show you the easy version (`ProgressMonitor`). The code example they use for the complex version is shockingly beginner unfriendly. Everything is bundled into a single class (and an inner class `Task`), literally creating a spaghetti-code form of relationships.

Comment: Hell, I'm not done. They acknowledged that this feature necessarily involves Swing Concurrency (fair), so we should probably use a SwingWorker (also fair). But then they picked the literal most complex and beginner unfriendly way to use it (call `setProgress` on your SwingWorker, then use a ***PropertyChangeListener*** to extract the field from the `"progress"` PropertyChangeEvent itself ***without telling you all of the hidden invariants, like it only accepts values from 0-100***). They could have started with the easier versions, like publish/process.

Comment: Oracle's Swing tutorials are normally excellent, but this one was an absolute stinker on an otherwise excellent track record. They should really rework that tutorial completely.

Comment: @davidalayachew There's many ways to skin this cat, the example above is just one.  Personally, I'm not a massive fan the `PropertyChangeListener` and would have preferred a dedicated listener, but `SwingWorker` was introduced in 1.6 and was adopted from an external developer.  I would say, in general, the original trails were of reasonable quality, but later trails suffered from a lack of time/talent and were probably written by engineers who had a deep understanding the system - always a bad place to start - these are just assumptions on my part, but yes, I found it a pain to learn it to

Comment: Happy to hear you can understand and relate. I only bring all of this up because, 99% of the time, you are correct - the Oracle tutorials are a great starting place for beginners. But I want people to know that they should steer clear for this one topic in particular.