# Display progress bar until downloading completes in background

Tags: java, swing, download, jframe, jprogressbar

I'm downloading a file from Google drive on the click of a button in my program. File Download works perfectly. But it kind of hangs the program, while it is downloading file. after downloading, program is normal again.

So, in the duration, it hangs. I wanted to show something like progress bar, or animation, or a new `JFrame` showing 'Please wait'. Even if I add the code of above Animation or frame before the code of download, it starts download, hanging the software, and when download finishes, it displays the frame window or animation.

Please help me. If I can use a progress bar, it would be a lot better. but it should not be connected to actual download progress and it should not have a cancel button.

Help me. If you need code of Download and Program, mention it and I will post.

Comment: Take a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) and [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html)

Comment: And for an [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24835638/issues-with-swingworker-and-jprogressbar/24835935#24835935)

Comment: How can i use Working threads in this?

Comment: You shouldn't, you should be using a `SwingWorker`, see the linked example